# Disable Elixir sourcemaps only for CSS and enabled for JS

Tags: laravel-elixir

Is there a way to disable Elixir generate sourcemaps for CSS only and keep it enabled for JS. Currently when I add below code, sourcemaps are not generated for both CSS and JS.

```
elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;
```

Comment: [`Elixir`](http://elixir-lang.org) is a great programming language, having nothing to do with `laravel`, please put the tags _accurately_.

Comment: @mudasobwa You clearly have no idea about Laravel's tool named elixir.

Comment: @Frondor I clearly have many ideas, but you might want to check tags history before leaving comments like that. I just was cleaning up [tag:elixir] feed from this garbage.